# How to structure this XML in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012, tags

I used the following SQL to create some temp tables and then using those temp tables I wanted to generate a XML. I am able to generate an XML but I just can not structure this thing the way I want.

I want to open the `IndirectSalesMessage` tag, then open the `Header` tag, then close the `<Header>` tag, then open the `DIST` tag, then close the `DIST` tag before finally closing the `IndirectSalesMessage` tag.

Here is the code I have now in SQL and what it does. The XML generated is below under "XML that I generate". The XML that I actually want to generate is below that under "XML that I want to generate".

```
-- Creation of #XML HEADER  
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [targetapplication], 
    [originatingapplication], 
    [interfacename], 
    '7320177' E1_num 
INTO
    #xml_header 
FROM   
    [CP].[dbo].[xmlforload] 

-- Creation of #DIST2 
SELECT 
    distributor_e1number, 
    debit_memo_number 
INTO
    #dist2 
FROM   
    #xml_dist 
WHERE  
    distributor_e1number = '7320177' 
    AND debit_memo_number = 'June20177320177' 

-- Creation of #XML
SELECT
    Header.[targetapplication], 
    Header.[interfacename], 
    Header.[originatingapplication], 
    DIST.distributor_e1number, 
    DIST.debit_memo_number 
FROM
    #xml_header Header 
INNER JOIN 
    #dist2 DIST ON header.e1_num = dist.distributor_e1number 
FOR XML PATH('Header'), ROOT('IndirectSalesMessage'), ELEMENTS
```

XML that I **currently generate**:

```
<IndirectSalesMessage>
   <Header>
      <TargetApplication>EnterpriseOne 9.1</TargetApplication>
      <InterfaceName>CA_Tracing</InterfaceName>
      <OriginatingApplication>Alliance-Model N</OriginatingApplication>
      <distributor_e1number>7320177</distributor_e1number>
      <debit_memo_number>June20177320177</debit_memo_number>
   </Header>
</IndirectSalesMessage>
```

XML that I **want to generate**:

```
<IndirectSalesMessage>
   <Header>
      <TargetApplication>EnterpriseOne 9.1</TargetApplication>
      <InterfaceName>CA_Tracing</InterfaceName>
      <OriginatingApplication>Alliance-Model N</OriginatingApplication>
   </Header>
   <DIST>
      <distributor_e1number>7320177</distributor_e1number>
      <debit_memo_number>June20177320177</debit_memo_number>
   </DIST>
</IndirectSalesMessage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creation of XML

```
SELECT 
Header.targetapplicatioAS 'Header/Targetapplication', 
Header.interfacename AS 'Header/Interfacename', 
Header.originatingapplication AS 'Header/Originatingapplication',
DIST.distributor_e1number AS 'DIST/distributor_e1number',
DIST.debit_memo_number AS 'DIST/debit_memo_number'
FROM #xml_header Header 
INNER JOIN #dist2 DIST ON 
header.e1_num = dist.distributor_e1number 
FOR XML PATH('IndirectSalesMessage')
```

Comment: Pintu, I have accepted yours as the answer.  Thank you very much.